# Non-breakable space in chapter name

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

How could I move last word in following example to the next row without making \newline (which will also effect ToC)? I need non-breakable space, however ~ doesn't work here at all. Thank you.

> \chapter{Loremipsum dolors ametsaet application ProblemName}

causes this: [image]

When I use `\\` in front of "ProblemName", it also effect ToC.

Comment: Set the heading ragged right.

Comment: Please, be more specific. I don't understand you. Thank you.

Comment: {\raggedright{\chapter{Works. Thanks, Johny}}}

Comment: Be more specific in the code you show. In general provide a small compilable document so we can see for example which document class you use. In general it is best to simply configure `\chapter` to always set its contents ragged right. But we cannot advise you on that without more information

Comment: which class are you using? the standard report and book classes set chapter headings raggedright, amsbook uses centering, so neither would make the output that you show.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an optional argument to `chapter`:

```
\chapter[Loremipsum dolors ametsaet application ProblemName]{Loremipsum dolors ametsaet application\\ ProblemName}
```

Alternatively, using `titlesec` to format the chapter layout, you can declare something like this

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\raggedright\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

Or you can insert a manual line break, and load `titlesec` with the `newlinetospace` option, which automatically converts line breaks to spaces for headers and table of contents.